# Error On My PHP Build On Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

To check whether my build configuration for PHP is working, I've created this PHP code:
(Sorry if it's too basic. I'm a beginner to PHP Development.)

```
<?php
  $output = "It works!";

  echo $output;
?>
```

My PHP Build configuration is this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["php", "$file"]
}
```

I always get this error on my Sublime Console:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['php', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\trial.php']]
[dir: C:\wamp\www]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\]
[Finished]
```

I've tried changing $file with 'C:\wamp\www\trial.php' but still the same.

I'm using Win8. Can somebody help me please? I'm a beginner to this kind of things. And I've found myself liking to work in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I suspect it is `php` it can't find, not `C:\\wamp\\www\\trial.php`

Comment: Sir Quentin, what do you suggest I should do for Sublime to find PHP build?
Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the directory where PHP is installed to your Windows PATH environment variable. Once you do that, restart Sublime and the build command should work fine.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, Sir MattDMo. But it got me this error:

Error trying to parse build system: Invalid escape in Packages\User\PHP.sublime-build:2:17


This is my current build code for PHP.sublime-build

    {
      "cmd": ["php", "C:\php\pear"]
    }


I got C:\php\pear from

    <?php
      echo ini_get('include_path');
    ?>


I don't know if what I'm doing is correct but based from what I have red in the internet, I am. Thank you for the help though, Sir MattDMo. I appreciate it.